# How do I manually install a bootloader for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, hp, bootloader

So I decided to dual boot with ubuntu and I found mines within my files in my laptop, version 18.04. I did all installation but the grub menu doesn't show up. So I figured I'd try loading it from boot menu. I found an option with my hardisk name Toshiba bla bla bla and chose it. Ubuntu did load. So I tried checking for my bootloader from windows local disk in the efi file. I did not find any bootloader that says ubuntu. There's only Microsoft, boot, and hp. I tried looking inside boot but the same thing happens. No ubuntu. so I was wondering if I could manually install ubuntu's bootloader and move it to my efi folder or probably another solution would help. I have a hp laptop with windows 10 alongside ubuntu 18.04. I'm pretty new to Linux, and I only understand some basics of it.

Comment: shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi are the normal names of the ubuntu bootloaders, and they should have been installed into the EFI partition at EFI/ubuntu (along with the grub.cfg config file).  A copy of  grubx64.efi ( and maybe shimx64.efi if secure boot is on) may have been put into EFI/Boot with the name bootx64.efi which would be the default boot for the device, so that seems to have been done, but the grub.cfg must be in EFI/ubuntu, so I don't know how your boot works without the ubuntu directory.

Comment: bootx64.efi is in the boot folder but there was not any ubuntu folder inside efi. So what i think is that I can't make the grub automatically boot but I have to manually boot it through my hard drive from the bootmenu. I was wondering if there was a way to install bootloader or do I have to re install ubuntu?

Comment: You can run grub-install from the install media onto your hard disk.  Do you have more than one disk?  Maybe the grub bootloader went to the other disk.  When you run the install media, is it sda1 instead of sdb or sdc?  That would cause a problem with the install.  Maybe best to run the boot-repair just for the report and post a link to it in your question. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have 1 disk, but I will try boot repair for sure. Oh and I also had once dual boot with kali and it did show up in the efi. I was able to boot to kali grub menu. I don't know if it's the problem with the ubuntu i installed or something else.

Comment: Can you run chkdsk on the efi FAT filesystem from either Windows or Ubuntu?  If you have filesystem problems, that might cause grub not to appear.

Comment: @ubfan1 hi sorry my laptop died yesterday, i was only able to answer you today.. so i did run chkdsk and nothing seems to be wrong. So I think i'll try downloading the new ubuntu or maybe if it still doesnt work i'll probably just use other os other than ubntu. Btw thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you neet to type in the terminal "sudo update-grub". this will detect witch OS you have (windows 10) and it will come into the bootloader.

Comment: I tried your solution too but it seems that it didn't work either. It did detect my OS but didn't show up in the bootloader. I'm thinking that my grub exist but it's in a different folder. Is it possible though?